# Get ID attribute of each form

Tags: javascript, html, console.log

I need to console log ID attribute of each form element on click. So if someone clicks not on the form element, I don't want to console log it.

Here's my code:

```
<form class="cf">
  <div class="half left cf">
    <input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" id="input-email" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="text" id="input-subject" placeholder="Subject">
  </div>
  <div class="half right cf">
    <textarea name="message" type="text" id="input-message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </div>  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="input-submit">
</form>
```

I tried :

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
console.log(e.target.id);
}, false);
```

It does console log, but everything on click, and I need only the ID attribute of each form on click.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just add a click listener event to your form.
Example:

```js
let forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');

function formClicked(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
}

forms.forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('click', formClicked, false);
});
```